# Not saving session data after log in

Tags: php, session

Hey there im trying to make a log in and register system where when the user log in in the header it shows him a message greeting him with his username and when he is not logged it shows him a message greeting him as a guest.
My problem is i suppose that in the header page (member.php page) the sessions are not saved and the user is never logged in.
While testing my code . The user after logging in successfully it redirect him to member.php page where it should show him the username and all that. Yet it doesn't.
Here are my codes :

member.php :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
  $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
  $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
      <head>

      <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/styletest.css" TYPE="text/css">

      </head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<!-- Website menu -->

        <div id="menu-bar">
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
        </div>  

<!-- End of Website menu -->

<div id="content">

<!-- Website header -->

        <div id="header">
            <h1>Testing header</h1>
      <?php

       if ($username && $userid) {

              echo "Welcome <b>$username</b>, <a href='./logout.php'>Logout</a>";

       } else {

              echo "Please login to access this page. <a href='./login.php'>Login here</a>";

       }

        ?>
        </div>  

<!-- End of Website header -->  

<!-- -----Website content----- -->      

<p>Testing website content</p>

<!-- End of Website content -->     
</div>

<!-- Website footer --> 

        <div id="footer">

        </div>

<!-- End of Website footer -->      

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is login.php :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
$_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
      <head>

      <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/styletest.css" TYPE="text/css">

      </head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<!-- Website menu -->

        <div id="menu-bar">
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testing links</a></li>
        </div>  

<!-- End of Website menu -->

<div id="content">

<!-- Website header -->

        <div id="header">
            <h1>Testing header</h1>
            <?php
             if ($username && $userid) {
             echo $username; 
            } else {
            echo 'Welcome guest';
            }

            ?>
        </div>  

<!-- End of Website header -->  

<!-- -----Website content----- -->      
<h2>Log in</h2>

<?php

$form='<form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="user"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password :</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" value="Log in"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>';

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass']; 

if ($_POST['loginbtn']) {

    if ($user) {

        if ($pass) {

            require 'core/connect.php';

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' ");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $passwordFromPost = $_POST['pass'];
            $hashedPasswordFromDB = $row['password'];

                if (password_verify($passwordFromPost, $hashedPasswordFromDB)) {

                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' ");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if ($numrows == 1) {

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' ");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $dbactive = $row['active'];
            $dbuser = $row['username'];


                            if ($dbactive == 1) {

                            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;    
                            echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b> <a href='./member.php'>Click here</a> to go back to home page";


                            } else {

                            echo '<font color="red">You must activate your account to log in.</font>';
                            echo $form;

                            }

                    } else {

                    echo '<font color="red">You entered an invalid username or password.</font>';
                    echo $form;

                    }

                } else {

                echo '<font color="red">You entered an invalid username or password.</font>';   
                echo $form;

                }

            mysql_close();

        } else {

        echo '<font color="red">You must enter your password.</font>';
        echo $form;

        }

    } else {

    echo '<font color="red">You must enter your username.</font>';  
    echo $form;

    }
}else{

echo $form; 

}
 ?>

 <!-- End of Website header --> 

<!-- -----Website content----- -->      

<p>Testing website content</p>

<!-- End of Website content -->     
</div>

<!-- Website footer --> 

        <div id="footer">

        </div>

<!-- End of Website footer -->      

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Now i don't think that in login.php there is any problem because i tested the page and every thing works fine even this code :

```
echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b> <a href='./member.php'>Click here</a> to go back to home page";
```

Where it shows him his username yet in member.php nothing happens.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to see if the session is set `isset()`. However, your variables don't seem to match. `$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];` and `$_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;` so hard to say what variables you want to actually use.

Comment: what do you mean ? i understood you but i didnt run in a similar problem before like this and never used isset() .. so i didnt quite catch you there :/

Comment: So if it worked before, what has changed since?

Comment: i edited them im using $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
$_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser; on both pages now

Comment: the problem is that i dont know ... it used to work but now no ... i retyped the whole code my self and then checked the one that worked before its the same ... only diff is the appearance and and the fields and etc ... but every thing in php is the same ...

Comment: Why do you turn off error reporting? Errors can be quite interesting when you are developing\

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems the variables `$username` and `$userid` are not initialized anywhere. Since your question involves sessions I assume you are getting those variables from the session. If they are being declared elsewhere, the sessions are not in use (according to your code).

In your `member.php` file you write:

```
$_SESSION['userid']   = $dbid;
$_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
```

This seems wrong, as you are **redeclaring** the values in the session and not simply fetching them. Use the following instead.

```
$username = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : false;
$userid   = isset($_SESSION['userid'])   ? $_SESSION['userid']   : false;
```

This will check if the username and user id are stored in the session. If they are missing the variables are assigned the value `false`. Then when you further down checks the variables, the condition will fail and execute the block regarding a guest user.

**Bonus**

You should also make it a habit checking if variables exists before using them. This will help you avoid `undefined variable` errors. Use the `isset` keyword to check. This may seem like more work, but the gain in robustness of your code cannot be compared to the time you (might) have to spend fixing simple errors.

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: i tried it ... didnt work :/ or maybe i did something wrong placing them but i dont think thats the problem ..